# AJAX.beginform is javascript,isn't it?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

There is Htmlhelper Ajax.BeginForm().I have a question. AJAX.beginform is javascript,isn't it?In other worlds,ASP.NET MVC converts  AJAX.BeginForm in javascript.

Comment: You can insert an Ajax.BeginForm() and see what html it produces.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. At least not completely. MVC will render a "standard" Html form and will attach events on the element. These events are the used for your callbacks (`OnBegin`, `OnComplete`,...). It provides a bigger list of options so that you can create a better user experience. For example, it lets you add a confirmation message, which is shown to the user before submitting the form. This is done by setting the `Confirm` property of the `AjaxOptions` property. Another advantage of this helper (and a handy one, I might say) is that it allows the asynchronous loading of data and changing a part of your web-page without the need of reloading it. This is done by setting the `UpdateTargetId` property.

To sum things up, `Ajax.BeginForm()` can be seen as a two-part tool: one standard Html form and one set of JavaScript tools for a richer user experience.

Comment: When I disable javascript in your browser,Ajax.BeginForm() stops working.Why is this happening?

Comment: If you disable JavaScript, the Html Helper generated code fails to execute. The helper generates the code which binds the Html form to the "submit" JavaScript event.